# Remove recipient details BCC from PHP Mailer

Tags: javascript, php, email

When I am trying to send multiple emails using php mailer, it displays all recipients addresses. All the mail recipients can find others email addresses whom I sent. Is it possible to remove others recipient addresses? Need to show the recipient only its recipient address not others.

Here is my Coding

```
$to_array = explode(",", $_REQUEST['Recipient']);
$mail->From = 'automail@domain.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Test Admin'; 
foreach ($to_array as $address) {
  $mail->AddAddress($address);
}
$mail->Subject = "$subject";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) it shows you how to add BCC addresses.

Comment: do not assign BCC "$mailer->AddBCC".

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want other users to see your recipients you can simply do a bcc

```
$to_array = explode(",", $_REQUEST['Recipient']);
$mail->From = 'automail@domain.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Test Admin'; 
foreach ($to_array as $address) {
  $mail->AddBCC($address);
}
$mail->Subject = "$subject";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->Send();
```

If you just want recipients email to display and not others you need to send them individually this way

```
$to_array = explode(",", $_REQUEST['Recipient']);
for($i=0; $i<count($to_array); $i++){
   $mail->From = 'automail@domain.com';
   $mail->FromName = 'Test Admin'; 
   $mail->AddAddress($to_array[$i]);
   $mail->Subject = "$subject";
   $mail->MsgHTML($body);
   $mail->Send();
}
```

First case wont display any `TO` email. Second case it will display only the recipient email.